# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Instance - debugging low CPU but high memory usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, memory, java, elastic-beanstalk

I'm running a small t1.micro instance on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk.  The app itself is a Java web server, uploaded via a .war file, that responds to requests from a remote Heroku web app.

Upon deploying the application, a combination of multipart form data as file input streams and application/json are posted to it from requests from the Heroku app.  For some reason, whenever a request is made, the health of the instance quickly jumps to Warning, and upon further requests inevitably jumps to Severe, and thus stops responding to any request.

I've been trying to figure out exactly why this is occurring.  One thing I recognized from the Health tab is that memory usage is almost consistently at >97% when responding to requests, while on the other hand, idle CPU is almost always > 99%.  This seems odd to me.

For example, suppose I decide to post a 50KB .pptx file to the Java web server (large enough to consistently crash the instance).  I upload it and POST it as a stream from the Heroku app to the Elastic Beanstalk instance.  The instance quickly jumps to Warning status, and then after 30 seconds or so of what I think is attempting to read/write the stream, jumps again to Severe and crashes.

Why would a 50KB file posted to the instance as a stream be large enough to crash the instance?  I'm finding it hard to download logs because they seem to take forever for AWS to generate.  Is there an easy way to increase the memory of the instance (i.e. should I jump to a higher tier of instance)?  Thanks for your help.